# How can I generate client code based on tags?

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger-codegen

I have one big API from a provider. I use only 3 operations (end points) out for more than 50.

Is there a way to generate client based only on tags ? since if i generate all, it adds unnecessary classes (req/reposnse objects etc.) to my classpath.

I use maven to generate the same.